# github.com/jolestar/go-commons-pool/v2: module github.com/jolestar/go-commons-pool/v2

Tags: go, goland

I need to download a third-party package in goland. However, it has always been timeout. I tried to change the https download to ssh, which seems to have any effect. It has always been timeout.

```
github.com/jolestar/go-commons-pool/v2: module github.com/jolestar/go-commons-pool/v2: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/jolestar/go-commons-pool/v2/@v/list": dial tcp 142.251.42.241:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Try to add `GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn` in _Preferences/Settings | Go | Go modules | Environment_.